# Java beginner question: Method for finding next available ID in an ArrayList

Tags: java

ive been given this Exercise: Make a method for finding the next available member ID in an ArrayList of member objects. I create the member ID's manually when creating a new member, and i can always assume that the members have been arranged in order by ID. 
For example: If i have 4 members with ID's from 0-3, and i remove the 2nd member, the method should return 1.

Here is the messy part i have for now:

```
public int getNextID (){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < members.size(); i++){
        if(i == members.get(i).getID()){
            i++;



        }
        else if(i != members.get(i).getID()){
            System.out.println("Next available ID:  " + i);

        } else {
            System.out.println("Next available ID: " + members.size());
            break;
        }
    }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you. Please do not just drop your assignment and your code ... to let it to the reader to figure "okay, is that code correct, or what". Tell us *how* you expect us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This solution provides a new Member ID from a List, where all MemberItems are sorted by ID. Item 0 in the List, must have the ID 0. Item 1 -> ID 1.
The new ID will always be the lowest available ID which is currently not assigned.*

---

#### Solution 1

```java
public int getNextID (){
    for(int i = 0; i < members.size(); i++){
        if(i < members.get(i).getID()){
            System.out.println("Next available ID:  " + i);
            // at this point we know this is the next id.
            // we can leave the method and return the next ID.
            return i;
        }
    }
    // we did not leave the loop (and method), because all id's are assigned.
    System.out.println("Next available ID:  " + members.size());
    return members.size();
}
```

---

#### Solution 2 (Java 1.8+ Stream)

If you prefer a 2 line java 8 stream solution you could also use this:

```java
public int getNextID() {
   Member m = members.stream().filter(member -> member.getID() != members.indexOf(member)).findFirst().orElse(null);
   return (m != null ? members.indexOf(m) : members.size());
}
```

#### Solution 3 (Java 1.8+ Stream)

or a 1 line stream solution:

```java
public int getNextID() {
   return members.stream().filter(member -> member.getID() != members.indexOf(member)).findFirst().map(m2 -> members.indexOf(m2)).orElse(members.size());
}
```

---

To say something about your code:
You are increasing `i` twice.
Once in the `for` statement at the end with `i++` and two lines below with `i++` again.
This way, you are skipping the index 1. if the first member has the same id like index.

---

#### Timings and testing

For anyone who is interested into the comparision of timings between the 3 solutions. This are the Timings from my maschine with java1.8:

```
|----------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 10000 Items, Free Position 9998    | 10000 Items, Free Position 1    |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Solution1: ~2ms                    |  Solution1: ~0.005ms            |  
| Solution2: ~65ms                   |  Solution2: ~0.05ms             |
| Solution3: ~60ms                   |  Solution3: ~0.06ms             |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Code to execute it on your maschine. will definitly result in different timing results, but the proportion should stay about the same.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    private static List<Member> members = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        members = getTestList(10000);

        warmUp();

        members.remove(9998);
        testSolutions();
        members.remove(1);
        testSolutions();

    }

    private static void warmUp() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for (Member m : members) {
                // warm up cpu for iteration
            }
            members.forEach(Member::getID);
        }
    }

    private static void testSolutions() {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        int result1 = getNextID();
        System.out.println("#1 Iterative result: " + result1 + " | in " + (System.nanoTime() - start) / 1000000.0 + "ms");
        start = System.nanoTime();
        Member m = members.stream().filter(member -> member.getID() != members.indexOf(member)).findFirst().orElse(null);
        int result2 = m != null ? members.indexOf(m) : members.size();
        System.out.println("#2 Stream Result: " + result2 + " | in " + ((System.nanoTime() - start) / 1000000.0) + "ms");
        start = System.nanoTime();
        int result3 = members.stream().filter(member -> member.getID() != members.indexOf(member)).findFirst().map(m2 -> members.indexOf(m2)).orElse(members.size());
        System.out.println("#3 Stream Result: " + result3 + " | in " + ((System.nanoTime() - start) / 1000000.0) + "ms");
    }

    private static int getNextID() {
        for (int i = 0; i < members.size(); i++) {
            if (i < members.get(i).getID()) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return members.size();
    }

    private static List<Member> getTestList(int count) {
        List<Member> members = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            members.add(new Member(i));
        }
        return members;
    }

    private static class Member {
        private int id;

        public Member(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        private int getID() {
            return id;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why we care about what is inside the list ? What is the relevance with the list content, so with the id ? The return should be always `members.size()` which is the next available for adding.

Comment: Because the purpose for his method is to get the next member ID. if the member with ID 3 (at index 3 in the list) is removed, he wants the next member who is created to get the now free ID 3. If this makes sense for storing or anything else was not the question.

Comment: Yes, he said that could reuse id, didn't read carefully. Your solution is fine.

Comment: One issue on run-time is the place where is a added an `deleted_id`. If is exactly on the same index as deleted one then the method will provide right id. [`add(nextId,obj_nextId)`]. If is added on bottom then you could provide again an existing id.[`add(obj_nextId)`]

Comment: No, it's your code. It work fine only when added the deleted index on the same place. Do not know how it will be used !

Comment: eg: `A001 obj = new A001();
  obj.l.add(obj.new Member(0));
  obj.l.add(obj.new Member(1));
  obj.l.add(obj.new Member(2));
  obj.l.add(obj.new Member(3));
  obj.l.add(obj.new Member(4));
  System.out.println(obj.getNextID());
  obj.l.remove(3);
  System.out.println(obj.getNextID());
  obj.l.add(obj.new Member(3));
  obj.l.forEach(System.out::println);
  System.out.println(obj.getNextID());
  obj.l.add(obj.new Member(3));
  obj.l.forEach(System.out::println);
  System.out.println(obj.getNextID());`

Comment: As he pointed out, it will be guaranteed that the list will be ordered to any time. But you are right. If this is not the case, the result are probably wrong in the most scenarios.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The first solution was just what i was looking for. I had something similar, but for some reason it didn't work as expected. I think i messed up with the return statements.

Comment: Glad it helped you. Let me give you an advice. If you don't already, start using a good IDE like IntelliJ or Eclipse, and try using the debugger tool. This way you can step through your code and see what it is doing with with the exact values. For this kind of issues, it's a great help.

Answer (score 0):

For List, use `size()` to get the number of elements.(also it's give you the last but 1 index used).
Index is starting from 0 and is automatically adjusted when adding or removing elements.
So you do not need to keep tracking manually for indexes. 

Note, when you add on list with method `add(index, element)` index should always be less then or equal to `size()`_methods return.

```
    List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
    l.add("a"); //auto index 0
    l.add("b"); //auto index 1
    l.add("c"); //auto index 2
    System.out.println(l.size()); //3 and it's also next_available for add at bottom
    l.remove(1);
    l.forEach(System.out::println); //a c
    System.out.println(l.size()); // 2
    System.out.println(l.get(0)); //a
    System.out.println(l.get(1)); //c adjusted index from 2 to 1 after remove
    l.add(2,"d");
    System.out.println(l.size()); //3
    l.add(4,"e"); //error  java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 3
```

Kindly see @Sunchezz and @Evan answers for a full solution.